# c variable to store in eax register

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

what am I doing wrong here?

```
int val = 15;
asm ("movl %1, %%eax"::"r"(val):"%eax" );
__asm__ volatile ("int $0x80");
```

I want to move 15 in eax and then call an interrupt

> "Error" : 'asm': operand number out of range

Comment: And what do you think does not work?

Comment: Do not edit your question by removing all the relevant text and asking to delete it. You can't delete it for a reason.

Answer (score 6):

Each `asm` construct is independent and values/registers set in one have no connection to the other.  In order to make this work, you need a single `asm`.  In addition, there's no need to actually move a value into eax -- that is what the "a" input constraint does.  So you want:

```
int val=15
asm volatile("int $0x80" : : "a"(val));
```

or just

```
asm volatile("int $0x80"::"a"(15));
```

**Edit**

The meaning of the various constraint letters is in [the gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html#Constraints), but basically, for x86 they are:

```
'r' -- any general register
'm' -- in memory addressable by an EA operand (base reg + index * scale + displacement)
'a' -- al/ax/eax/rax register (depending on the size of the operand)
'b' -- bl/bx/ebx/rbx register
'c' -- cl/cx/ecx/rcx register
'd' -- dl/dx/edx/rdx register
'A' -- edx:eax register pair (holding a 64-bit value)
'D' -- di/edi/rdi
'S' -- si/esi/rdi
'f' -- any 8087 fp register
't' -- ST(0) -- top of 8087 stack
'u' -- ST(1) -- second on 8087 stack
'y' -- any MMX register
'x' -- any XMM register
```

If you want to put multiple things in specific registers, you need multiple inputs, each with the appropriate constraint.  For example:

```
int read(int fd, void *buf, int size) {
    int rv;
    asm ("int $0x80" : "=a"(rv) : "a"(3), "b"(fd), "c"(buf), "d"(size) : "memory");
    return rv;
}
```

makes a 'read' system call directly.  The input constraints put the various parameters in the eax/ebx/ecx/edx registers, and the return value ends up in the eax register.

For the constraints that don't correspond to a specific register, you would use `%n` in the asm string, and it gets replaced by the register chosen by the compiler, but for constraints that correspond to specific registers, there is no need to mention it directly.

Comment: Chris's answer puts `val` in eax before the asm block begins. That's what the `"a"(val)` is for.

Comment: where does he put it in eax? I want to specifically add it register eax manually

Comment: @zoy.khan: `"a"(val)` **is** specifically saying "put `val` in `eax`. this answer is giving you the correct way to do it. The reason why this is the correct approach, is that it allows the compiler to know the relationship between `eax` and the inline assembly. So optimizations won't mess it up. If he had written `"b"(val)`, then it would use `ebx`. This is just how it is done.

Comment: Evan what if a sys call requires 3 registers , and then do a interrupt. How would you do that?

Comment: @zoy.khan: Then you create inputs for both.  `"a"(val), "b"(other_val)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like he is putting x into EAX explicitly in the following code example:

[What is r() and double percent %% in GCC inline assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589157/need-some-help-understanding-gcc-inline-assembly-language?rq=1)

i compiled that code with g++ and ran it through gdb.
Within gdb, *info register eax* showed the correct number

What compiler and operating system and architecture are you using?  If you are using 64bit MSVS, then inline assembly is not possible.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

cout << "Compile via: g++ -O0 -ggdb -o asm.out asm.cpp" << endl;
cout << "Want to put 15 into register EAX and then call an interrupt." << endl;
cout << "gdb ./asm.out  --> stepi --> info register eaain." << endl;

int eaxin = 15, eaxout=0, ebxin=33, ebxout=0;
cout << "Before calling assembly routines:" << endl;
cout << "eaxin=" << eaxin << "\t" << "eaxout=" << eaxout << "\t" ;
cout << "ebxin=" << ebxin << "\t" << "ebxout=" << ebxout << endl;

asm ("movl %1, %%eax;"
     "movl %%eax, %0;"
    :"=r"(eaxout)   /* 1  eaxout is output operand 1 */
    :"r"(eaxin)     /* 0  eaxin is input operand 0*/
    :"%eax"
    );   /* %eax is clobbered register.  Why not two percent signs here? */

//Lets play in the ebx register.
asm ("movl %1, %%ebx;"
     "inc %%ebx;"
     "inc %%ebx;"
     "movl %%ebx, %0;"
    :"=r"(ebxout) 
    :"r"(ebxin) /* "+" is supposed to allow input and output but did not work */
    :"%ebx"
    ); 


//Call the system interrupt 128.
asm volatile ("int $0x80");

cout << "After calling assembly routines. Value of eaxout should have changed." << endl;
cout << "eaxin=" << eaxin << "  " << "eaxout=" << eaxout << "\t" ;
cout << "ebxin=" << ebxin << "\t" << "ebxout=" << ebxout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589157/need-some-help-understanding-gcc-inline-assembly-language?rq=1" << endl;
cout << "Note: inline assembly CANNOT be done with MS VisualStudio 64bit." << endl;
cout << "   option1:   Use a separate file for the assembler code." << endl;
cout << "   option2:   Use instrinsics." << endl;
cout << " Look for intrn.h at http://software.intel.com/en-us    /node/181178?wapkw=ain86_64+assembly "  << endl;
return 0;
}
```

*(gdb) info register eax ebx

     eax            0xf      15

     ebx            0x0      0

   (gdb) step

     35      asm volatile ("int $0x80");

   (gdb) info register eax ebx

     eax            0x23     35

     ebx            0x23     35*

Comment: I want to learn how to store a variable on ebx or eax from a c variable, please help

Comment: Click on the link in my answer.  It explicitly references eax.  You may want to start with turning off all compiler optimizations to make it less likely eax gets clobbered with other data before the interrupt gets serviced.