# What does a double-percent sign (%%) do in gcc inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, x86

I came across a code that looks like this:

```
asm volatile (
    # [...]
    "movl $1200, %%ecx;"
    # [...]
);
```

I know what `movl $1200, %ecx` does in x86. but I was confused by why there are two percent signs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GCC inline assembly uses %0, %1, %2, etc. to refer to input and output operands.  That means you need to use two %% for real registers.

Check this [howto](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) for great information.

Answer (score 8):

**It depends**

- if there is a colon `:` after the string, then it is an [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), and `%%` escapes the percent which could have especial meanings [as mentioned by Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745659/895245). Example:

  ```
  uint32_t in = 1;
  uint32_t out = 0;
  asm volatile (
      "movl %1, %%eax;"
      "inc %%eax;"
      "movl %%eax, %0"
      : "=m" (out) /* Outputs. '=' means written to. */
      : "m" (in)   /* Inputs. No '='. */
      : "%eax"
  );
  assert(out == in + 1);
  ```
- otherwise, it will be a compile time error, because without colon it is a [basic asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm) which does not support variable constraints and does not need or support escaping `%1`. E.g.:

  ```
  asm volatile ("movl $1200, %ecx;");
  ```

  works just fine.

Extended asm is more often used since it is much more powerful.

Comment: *works just fine.* - Well, it compiles and assembles just fine, but you can never use it safely, except in the body of a `__attribute__((naked))` function, or at global scope to similarly define the entire body of a function without any interaction with compiler-generated code (except via the calling convention).  You can only safely use this anywhere else with a clobber or `"=c"` output operand to tell the compiler that ECX no longer has its original value after this asm runs.

Comment: Even moreso than https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm, really *never* use Basic asm.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended.

Answer (score 0):

This helps GCC to distinguish between the operands and registers. operands have a single % as prefix. '%%' is always used with registers.